# How to access Firestore from iOS and nodejs

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, actions-on-google

My question is how to access and modify Firestore when accessed by `iOS` app and Actions on Google.

I have written code correctly which is I’m confident about because from both sides I have done write and read transactions.

But when I do a write to `firestore` using `Nodejs`, I can’t access the written data from `iOS` app using `Swift`.

For example `db.collection(hi).doc(uid).set(sth)` in node is and then when I access the sth by swift such as by writing like this : `db.collection(hi).document(uid).getDocument....` Likewise, written data by swift can’t be accessed by `nodejs`

There’s no error in the console so I can’t figure out how to handle this strange behavior

**UPDATE**

Sorry there were errors

> Encounter network error. Code, error: -1009, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1d0640a50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}

And below

> Task <32F439B8-6B22-4E3C-A8F6-9D596F5EB068>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1009

**Edit(Solved)**

Okay so I started thinking away from the guess that there is a code or firestore setting problem, but instead I investigated in a different way. The solution was that in the App Setting, I turned off the mobile connection of my app. I'm not sure when this happened. So there was no problem with any code.

Comment: Do you see the data being updated in the Firebase console?

Comment: @NickFelker Nope. It is not reflected. For example, if I set boolean key called 'flag', which is set to false and set in the firestore, and then I update flag to true from iOS app and after that when I access it from iOS, the flag is true, but from nodejs (google assistant), the flag is still false.

Comment: I updated console log. I found out that there are a bunch of messages which say the mobile app is now in offline mode.... But then why I succeeded in creating a transaction to firestore from iOS. It is very strange

Comment: I am sure that it is not cached data btw. Because the transaction making a new root path is clearly created in the firestore from iOS app besides a bunch of other root paths created by nodejs. I can't get values from paths created by nodejs

Comment: The Firebase web console is the source of truth for data. If it's not updated there, the data isn't truly updated. On iOS, Firestore will cache changes for fast recall, which is why you may be able to recall it that way.

Comment: So you mean there is a function that disables the fast recall? Or is there any place to do this? Like google.plist file or something

Comment: @NickFelker thanks for your help, the issue got solved.